# Can you cross jump pads without getting launched?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Occasionally I'd like to continue moving past the jump pads without taking advantage of the jump effect.  They throw you so high, that if you fall back down to the level you began on, you take a pretty substantial cut of fall damage.

In the image below, for example, I'd just like to get to the shrine.  There are tons of other situations where all I want to do is continue moving along in my search for the teleporter, and jump pads often cause me to get hurt.

Is there a way around this?

[image: A shrine, a jumper, and a me]

Comment: I know you can control the height of your jump while using a jump pad. If you do not hold 'jump' while on the pad, do you really take fall damage? I do not remember taking fall damage from just running into the pad without actually jumping.

Comment: Yeah, you do.  I can check again later today, but I'm pretty sure you take fall damage no matter what.  I have found some ways to get around this though, will post them eventually.

Comment: Has this been changed in an update or something? I use them all the time and land on the same level, taking no fall damage.

Answer (score 9):

Jump pads become inactive when time is frozen with the Unstable Stopwatch item.

Answer (score 8):

The Huntress has a dash move that is actually a blink; it will move you through a teleporter.  No other champion appears to have a "horizontal" movement ability that can be used to bypass a teleporter in this fasion.

The only other options are unfortunately also situational:

1. Jump over the pad with your item-enhanced-jump.
2. If the platform above isn't too high, you can just fall down and angle left.

Comment: The commando roll does not pass through jump pads.  I haven't tried with the Miner, but his dashes can also be used to negate fall damage (same with the commando).

Comment: @GnomeSlice - correct; I ran it as part of my testing and confirmed.  It was only the Huntress that could do it; Mercenary and Miner were unable (unless I wasn't positining properly with the Miner, but I doubt it).

Comment: Also confirmed with the Miner; I was not able to travel over or through the pad either.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the loader, if there is a wall on the other side of course. You'll have to use your C button or your grappling hook arm thingy to pull yourself to the other side. I've been playing with the loader for a time now and I'm 100% sure you can get through it if you use your pull. c:

Answer (score -1):

In the current version, I have not been able to get past the launcher. I am going to say no.